# Fail if --build-arg is not passed

Tags: docker, docker-build

I have this in a Dockerfile:

```
ARG aws_access_key_id
ARG aws_secret_access_key
```

even though I did not use any --build-arg options, it still built successfully, how can I make it fail if those arguments are missing?

Comment: While @kichik's answer will certainly "work", you should not be using ARG for secrets, as they will be visible to anybody with access to the image via `docker history <image-name>. Use ENV instead for secrets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set some default values that will never be used and then test if those are the values. For example:

```
FROM alpine
ARG arg=NO_VALUE
RUN [ ! "${arg}" == "NO_VALUE" ]
```